# Slice a data frame based on a boolean condition, multiply by constant and assign the values back to the data frame. Doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to slice a data frame based on a boolean condition, multiply the series by a constant and assign the results back to the original data frame. I can do all this apart from assigning it back to the original data frame.

Here is an example:

```
df = {'a':[10,20,30,40,50,60], 'b':[110,120,130,140,150,160], 'c':[210,220,230,240,250,260]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df
    a   b   c
0   10  110 210
1   20  120 220
2   30  130 230
3   40  140 240
4   50  150 250
5   60  160 260

# I can slice it:
df.loc[df['a']>30, 'a'].iloc[0:2] 
3    40
4    50
Name: a, dtype: int64

# I can multiply it by a constant:
df.loc[df['a']>30, 'a'].iloc[0:2] * 2
3     80
4    100
Name: a, dtype: int64

# But, trying to assign it back doesn't work:
df.loc[df['a']>30, 'a'].iloc[0:2] = df.loc[df['a']>30, 'a'].iloc[0:2] * 2 
df
    a   b   c
0   10  110 210
1   20  120 220
2   30  130 230
3   40  280 240
4   50  300 250
5   60  160 260
```

Why? What am I  missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are creating a [chained assignment](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-and-selecting-data).  Where pandas is creating a new object in memory which you are updating that it isn't flowing back through to the original dataframe because of the multiple `__getitem__` calls.

Here is one way do you it using a signle .loc and the assignment operator `*=`.

```
df.loc[df[(df['a']>30)].head(2).index,'a'] *= 2
```

Output:

```
     a    b    c
0   10  110  210
1   20  120  220
2   30  130  230
3   80  140  240
4  100  150  250
5   60  160  260
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by creating a temporary variable that holds the dataframe that is returned by the `loc` query:

```
import pandas as pd

df = {'a': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60], 'b': [110, 120, 130,
                                           140, 150, 160], 'c': [210, 220, 230, 240, 250, 260]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

# Hold dataframe returned from query
tmp_slice = df.loc[df['a'] > 30, 'a']
# Apply changes to slice of queried dataframe
tmp_slice.iloc[0:2] = df.loc[df['a'] > 30, 'a'].iloc[0:2] * 2

# Apply they modified queried dataframe back to original dataframe
df.loc[df['a'] > 30, 'a'] = tmp_slice
```

`df` output:

```
     a    b    c
0   10  110  210
1   20  120  220
2   30  130  230
3   80  140  240
4  100  150  250
5   60  160  260
```